# Calling from classic ASP to a SQL Server stored procedure that has a binary datatype input parameter

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I have to call a stored procedure in a SQL Server database from classic asp (VBScript)

The problem is that one of the parameters of the stored procedure is of type "binary(1)".
I have looked at the VBscript data type constants for ADO and it seems that the equivalence for SQL binary types is AdBinary, but I don't know how to deal with this kind of data type from classic ASP. 
I have tried to set the value but I get wrong type errors. Is it possible in classic ASP to convert a numeric or a string value to binary data?

Invoking the same procedure using a query string like "Exec Procedure..." seems to work just concatenating the value for the binary parameter, but I have no idea of how to do the same using the ADODB.Command object.

Maybe someone have faced this situation before?

```vb
Dim bvalue 
Dim Conn
Dim objCommand
Dim RS
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open CONNECTION_STRING
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = Conn
objCommand.CommandText = "GetBinaryId"
objCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
objCommand.NamedParameters = True
bvalue = 15
objCommand.Parameters.Append objCommand.CreateParameter("@Id",adBinary,adParamInput,1,bvalue) 

 set RS = objCommand.Execute
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Also useful resource - [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97) best ADO constant guide I've found on the web.

Comment: Ok, updated with code, but it is just a standard call to a stored procedure, the problem is the binary input parameter

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It seems all you need is to assign the `.Value` property

Comment: @MCND The OP is already setting the `.Value` property using the `.CreateParameter()` method, `.Value` is set by the 5th argument.

Comment: @AlejandroMartin Your passing an `Int` and it's expecting `Binary` data. It would be easier to pass the value as an `adinteger` in your Stored Procedure` and just use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @Id)`. Save yourself a lot of grief trying to convert to Binary using VBScript.

Comment: @Lankymart, yes, you are right, but sometimes not setting the size nor the value in the `CreateParameter` call and assigning the `.Value` property solve some of this problems (and don't ask me why, i don't know, i just say i have seen it).

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, I think that avoiding binary parameters when working with VBScript will be the way to go from now on. Good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bvalue` must be a **binary** type.

I would check the type of data you have in `bvalue` by using `btype = varType(bvalue)` and see what you get, it should be `17` for byte.

If it's not `17`, then you need to make it `17`.

You can use this function to do that:

```vb
'Stream_StringToBinary Function
'2003 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
'Text - string parameter To convert To binary data
'CharSet - charset of the Text - default is "us-ascii"

Function Stream_StringToBinary(Text, CharSet)
  Const adTypeText = 2
  Const adTypeBinary = 1

  'Create Stream object
  Dim BinaryStream 'As New Stream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText

  'Specify charset For the source text (unicode) data.
  If Len(CharSet) > 0 Then
    BinaryStream.CharSet = CharSet
  Else
    BinaryStream.CharSet = "us-ascii"
  End If

  'Open the stream And write text/string data To the object
  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.WriteText Text


  'Change stream type To binary
  BinaryStream.Position = 0
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  'Ignore first two bytes - sign of
  BinaryStream.Position = 0

  'Open the stream And get binary data from the object
  Stream_StringToBinary = BinaryStream.Read
End Function
```

Then pass it to your command like this instead `Stream_StringToBinary(bvalue,"")`